# Posicionamento dinâmico das DIV's

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Olá, Estou enfrentando um problema, quero que as div's se alinhem automaticamente com o espaço vazio, conforme sinalizado, porém, ela insiste em ficar alinhada a sua div lateral e não a sua superior. Como devo proceder para ajustar isto?

[image: Exemplo]